# UWP: Conditionally Navigating from OnNaviagted to another page without input

Tags: c#, object, navigation, uwp

When the application runs, I want to check a condition that will determine where the page navigates to. There isn't any input from the user so there isn't an Object sender. How can I accomplish this?

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var Albums = await App.DataModel.GetAlbum();

        if (Albums != null)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(ViewModel.AlbumView));
        }
        else
        {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(ViewModel.AddAlbumView));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean this is the first page that will be loaded? Because if not, isn't there a point where the actual navigation is triggered? If so do the check there and navigate...

Comment: The condition determines which page will be the Entry point of the application.

Comment: Then you'll best move the check to your app.xaml.cs where the first page will be initiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the App.Xaml.cs there is line in the **OnAppLaunchedEvent**

```
rootframe.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```

replace this with your condition

```
    var Albums = await App.DataModel.GetAlbum();

    if (Albums != null)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(ViewModel.AlbumView));
    }
    else
    {
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(ViewModel.AddAlbumView));
    }
```

and don't forget to bring your albums and viewmodel into app.
Just as a good practice make the **viewModel** static and ref it in
other pages that require it . this ensures u are following a **SingleTon** 
pattern and u dont have multiple copies of ur Viewmodel at the same time.